# Add the last item that has been removed from the array

Tags: reactjs

I am using "input type=file multiple", and I have do list the files selected with the option to delete the selected file off that list.the problem that i have is that i can't add the last item that I removed.
suppose that you wanna add the last file that you has been removed (for error you has deleted that file and you have to add),well i can't do that, i can't add that file

```
 handleFile = e  => {
    let file = e.target.files   
    for(let i = 0,f; f = file[i]; i ++){
          this.list.push(`${f.name } (${f.size})`)
          this.setState({fileArray: [ ...this.list]})
    }
}
handleRemoveFile = e => {
    this.setState({fileArray: this.state.fileArray.filter(f => {
         return f !== e
        })
    })
     this.list = this.list.filter(f => {
        return f !== e
      })
}

// in render I have
<input id="file-upload" type="file" multiple onChange={this.handleFile}/>
<div>
{this.state.fileArray != undefined&& this.state.fileArray.length>0 ?      
  this.state.fileArray.map((f,index) => {
        return 
    <div style={{display: 'flex'}} key={index}>
           <p> { `${f}`} </p>
           <i className={`fa fa-check ${s.check}`}></i>
      <span onClick={()=>this.handleRemoveFile(f)} 
            style={{marginLeft:'1%'}}>
         <i className={`fa fa-trash-alt ${s.trash}`}></i>
      </span>
    </div>
}) : ''}
```

Comment: "i can't add the last item that I removed.". I can't understand it. Why do you want to add something that you just removed? Where do you want to add that file that you removed? If you are removing something, you should not add it in any place

Comment: Broda Noel when i remove all items to the list but i wanna add the last item that i remove for error (for example) i can't do that, and i don't no why

Comment: You can't do it because you removed it. You remove it. It disappeared. You removed it in `handleRemoveFile`.
You may have to add more information in your question, explaining what is `list`, and `filterArray` arrays. You have to explain a bit better what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand very well what you said, but I believe that you are having some problems filtering the file (hidding it) after clicking on `Remove`, right?

The problem is that you are filtering comparing object:

```
this.setState({
  fileArray: this.state.fileArray.filter(f => {
    return f !== e
  })
})
```

Comparing `f` and `e` is a bad idea, mainly in this part of the code:

```
this.list = this.list.filter(f => {
  return f !== e
})
```

Because the `e` object is part of `this.state.fileArray`, so, `e` is not present in `list`.

I'd recommend 2 ways to do it:

1. The good way: Check if `f` and `e` has a unique property that you can use to compare. For example: `f.id !== e.id` or `f.fileName !== e.fileName`
2. The Ugly: Instead of sending the `file` object to the `handleRemove` function, send the `index`. So, you should do `<span onClick={()=>this.handleRemoveFile(index)}`, and then:

```
handleRemoveFile = index => {
    this.setState({fileArray: this.state.fileArray.filter((f, i) => {
         return f=index !== i
        })
    })
     this.list = this.list.filter((f, i) => {
        return index !== i
      })
}
```

Comment: Broda the item contain a string ["Capture7.PNG (10128)", "Capture9.PNG (10276)"] (the name and the size of the file), all is ok when i add and remove, the problem is that I can't add the last item that was remove. thx for you you time and you help!!